# Thread is blocked in django - Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, multithreading

the last 4 hours I have been trying to understand threading with django. Nothing seems to work. I want to let the website run in the foreground and let the backend communicate with some other devices on a thread. I want the thread to start at the startup of the website but the program is stuck when I call the thread until the thread comes to an end.
Do you know a way to fix it? Please I need help.

The urls.py file

```
def add(x, y):
    i=0

    while i < 100000000:
        x += y
        i += 1

def postpone(function):
    t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(1,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    return 0

print("Before thread")

postpone(add(4,4))

print("After thread")
```

The server will not start until the while loop is finished.

Thanks for reading, I hope someone knows an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` function is called before the thread started, you need to pass `add` as reference though.

```
# decomposition 
# first, add gets called
r = add(4,4)
# then the result is passed to func `postpone`
postpone(r)

# postpone accept a function and args, which eventually get passed to the function
def postpone(function, *args):
    t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=args)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    return 0

print("Before thread")
# pass func as a reference, also send args to the postpone func also
postpone(add, 4,4)
print("After thread")
```